# Имитация свайпа по кнопке

Tags: java, android

Допустим, есть некоторая кнопка и при нажатии на нее нужно создать свайп вправо. 
Как реализовать подобное и возможно ли это?

Comment: посмотрите здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420320/perform-swipe-on-screen-using-accessibilityservice

Comment: Вы хотите нажимать кнопку в эмуляторе Android Studio или почему в заголовке и в тексте указана эта IDE?

Comment: Эникейщик, кнопку необходимо нажимать как в эмуляторе AS, так и в готовом приложении на физическом устройстве. В заголовке написал AS для понимания того, какую среду разработки использую.

Comment: Код от среды разработки не зависит, можно писать хоть в Блокноте.

Comment: Понял, принял :D
Изменил заголовок и текст вопроса

Comment: Кнопка (button) не должна свайпиться, это не вписывается в рамки нормального UX. Поэтому и ответа скорее всего не дождетесь. Никто такого не делал и вряд-ли будет пробовать ради вас :)

Comment: Eugene Krivanja, идея в том, чтобы создать жест в центре экрана по нажатию кнопки, а не свайпить саму кнопку